# PySide Installation error with Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: pip, pyside, python-3.6

I am trying to install PySide on Python36-32 but faced some problem during the installation. In my laptop, there is currently Python27 with PySide installed on it. However, due to the QString conversion issue in Python27,  I have to switch to use Python3.

Below are the error messages during the installation, not sure if it PySide version not available in Python36-32 or other issue.

- First Try

```
    C:\Users\Maybel>pip3 install PySide
    Collecting PySide
      Using cached PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Maybel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xk_u6djn\PySide\
```

- Try to upgrade setuptools because this is one of the way suggested online
  [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3884)

```
    C:\Users\Maybel>pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
    Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\maybel\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages

    C:\Users\Maybel>pip install PySide
    Requirement already satisfied: PySide in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

- Second Try after upgrade the setuptools

```
    C:\Users\Maybel>pip3 install PySide
    Collecting PySide
      Using cached PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Maybel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6zrldsw7\PySide\
```

- Try to use **pip install PySide**

```
    C:\Users\Maybel>pip install PySide
    Requirement already satisfied: PySide in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

Please advice. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2):

I see this in the error output:

```
only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
```

I.e. PySide checks Python's version and refuses to work with 3.6.

Comment: PySide works perfectly fine with Python-3.6. The problem is with pip3, not PySide.

Comment: @ekhumoro How do you explain the error message? I just downloaded PySide from PyPI and found the error message comes from `setup.py`.

Comment: Not sure, but I have PySide-1.2.4 installed and working with Python-3.6.2 on Arch Linux. I had a look at the [PKGBUILD](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/python-pyside), but I don't see any patches or other funky stuff required to compile it.

Comment: @ekhumoro Perhaps Arch developers patched PySide. Prisitne version clearly lists compatible Python versions.

Comment: Did you read my comment? No, it has not been patched in any way.

Comment: Either they patched `setup.py` or built the package without `setup.py` at all.

Comment: No, the problem is actually the [shiboken tool](https://shiboken.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that generates the pyside bindings. The Arch Linux [PKGBUILD](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/shiboken) for that does include a patch.

Comment: @phd was right that my Python 2.7 doesn't support PySide. I switched to Python 3.4 and try install PySide, this shld work for some ppl. But for my case, I faced some issues with "Failed to find cmake and followed by qmake not found after cmake successfully installed. Forgot to mention, I'm using Windows.

Comment: @user317130. PySide most certainly *does* support Python-2.7 (and I don't think phd said it didn't). It also works fine with Python-3.5 and Python-3.6 - but it seems those versions aren't **officially** supported at the moment. There is an [issue on the PySide tracker](https://github.com/pyside/PySide/issues/132) relating to this. Unfortunately, it seems patching the installers is much easier to do on Linux than it is on Windows. Even worse, the PySide devs appear quite reluctant to spend time on it at the moment, as all their efforts are now concentrated on PySide2.

Comment: @user317130. PS: someone managed to create some Windows binaries for Python-3.5, which can be found [here](https://github.com/krrr/PySide/releases). They are provided as wheels, so you should be able to install them via pip3.